Why can't I change the size of my dev drive?
A couple months ago, I created a 100GB Dev Drive to put all my projects on. So far, it works fine, but I'm starting to run out of space and I wanted to extend it's size. However, when I attempt to, I'm completely unable to.
Why is this? The dialog mentions that unmovable files may limit the minimum size of the volume, but it doesn't say anything about limits on the maximum size. The SSD this dev drive is located on also has over a terabyte left in space, so I don't think that can be what's limiting it.




Show disk layout in diskmgmt.msc , DiskGenius or other tool: there could be vital files for the next partition immediately after D:.

You might have a windows recovery partition or some other partition after your dev drive blocking its expansion, with diskmgmt.msc we are in the dark.  Software like gparted can be used on a USB drive to boot your computer and repartition and/or move the space.

It's a dev drive, essentially a VHD. It's not a physical volume and has no other partitions.

As it turns out, the dev drive interface in Settings is just terrible UX. Here's how I managed to expand the disk:

Take the dev drive offline in disk management
Open up powershell as admin
Navigate to the location where you've stored the dev drive's VHDX file
Back up your file
Resize-VHD -Path .\drive.vhdx -SizeBytes 150GB
Take the drive back online in disk management
Right click the partition and hit extend volume
Now you can extend the drive to the size you want.

Settings does not mention anything about this and only offers you to extend the partition. But this doesn't make sense, because dev drives are created with only one partition in the first place.

Thanks, I recently run into the similar issue, this works like a charm
